# Can the Scrollto plugin search within a separate div?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

heres some background info:

I want to make a menu where clicking on a link scrolls to a specific div within a div. the 'separate div that contains the div i want to scroll to' is also draggable with the dragscroll plugin. because of this, the links cannot be in the same div that will be scrolling. the link menu is outside the draggable div completely.

I have both plugins playing nice with eachother. the div can be drag-scrolled. but when i click on a link the ENTIRE page scrolls down a little instead of the content within the draggable div scrolling.

how can i bring the scope of the scrollto plugin down so it only tries to scroll within my div?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using [this scrollTo plugin?](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'dragscroll' plugin, but is this what you're after?

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    // grab the href from the link, it should correspond with the ID of the element you want to scroll to
    var id = $(this).attr("href");

    // tell your container to start scrolling to the element
    $("#yourDraggableContainer").scrollTo($(id), 800);

    // prevent default behaviour of links
    return false;
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kat8t/10/

Comment: Ah, i wish i knew how to use jsfiddle... anyway this is the plugin.http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html  i want to be able to scroll to the light blue elements on a big background

Comment: ...also, imagine some blue elements are off-screen, and by clicking a link outside the box it would scroll to a new lightblue element INSIDE the box

Comment: Okay, this seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/Kat8t/26/ Basically it's the same as I did in my answer, telling the container (`#viewport` in the example) to scroll to a specific element (`#inner`)

Comment: hmm..the thing worked the first time, with smooth scrolling from the scrollto. now though the jsfiddle is telling me to download the files to my own host.. and the effects are gone. its just a hard anchor link. i added your new code to the javascript on my file- its a hard anchor link then scrollto affects the entire page.